# Как убрать сокращение E+ в больших числах на PHP?

Tags: php, числа, формат

У меня через `fwrite(STDOUT, $bignum)` должно вывестись число такое, какое оно есть, а выходит с этими больными 1.1337228E+12. Что делать?!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приблизительно так, [PHP-документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php).

[Пример](http://ideone.com/o9g627):

```
$n = 1.1337228E+12;
echo number_format($n, 2, ".", "");
//1133722800000.00
```